# Data is not ordered correctly with pagination: Sql server and Hibernate 3.6.10

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008

**EDIT**: *the problem is related to the presence of subqueries in the select part of the translated query. This seems to mess with the numbering given by
the pagination.*

We recently changed dialect from `SqlServerDialect` to `SqlServer2008Dialect` in out hibernate configuration and hibernate it's starting to translate the queries that are paginated with this sql server query:

```
   WITH query AS (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by this_.numero asc) as __hibernate_row_nr__, 
                    this_.id as id834_0_, this_.numero as numero834_0_, this_.ragione_sociale as ragione9_834_0_, this_.anagrafica_fiscale as anagrafica10_834_0_, 
                    this_.partita_iva as partita11_834_0_, this_.codice_fiscale as codice12_834_0_, this_.note as note834_0_, this_.data_prospect_dal as data14_834_0_, 
                    this_.dt_inserimento as dt15_834_0_, this_.dt_modifica as dt16_834_0_, this_.nome as nome834_0_, this_.cognome as cognome834_0_, 
                    this_.dt_nascita as dt19_834_0_, this_.fl_piva_duplicata as fl20_834_0_, this_.mail_cliente as mail21_834_0_, this_.fl_capogruppo as fl22_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e2_crm_prospects as fk26_834_0_, this_.fl_duplicato as fl23_834_0_, this_.fl_a_consumo as fl4_834_0_, 
                    this_.codice_importazione as codice24_834_0_, this_.codice_attivita as codice38_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk5_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk6_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk7_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_decod_classe_dim_pr as fk27_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e0_decod_tipo_prospect as fk28_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_decod_codice_ateco as fk29_834_0_, this_.fk_comune_di_nascita as fk30_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e0_decod_gp_ind_com as fk31_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_decod_seg_com as fk32_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_decod_sotto_seg_com as fk33_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e0_natura_cliente as fk34_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_nazione_nascita as fk36_834_0_, this_.fk_e0_decod_prov_pros as fk35_834_0_, 
                    this_.fk_e2_com_punto_stradario as fk37_834_0_, replace(replace(replace(this_.ragione_sociale,'.',''),'-',''),' ','') as formula1662_0_, 
                    ( select u.user_logged from users u                  join e2_crm_dett_prospects p on u.id = p.fk_e0_decod_gestore_prospect                   
                        where p.fk_e2_crm_prospect = this_.id                    and p.fk_e0_prof_nodo = this_.fk_e0_prof_nodo) as formula1663_0_, 
                    ( select s.descrizione from e0_decod_tipi_stato_prospect s                join e2_crm_dett_prospects p on s.id = p.fk_e0_decod_stato_prospect
                        where p.fk_e2_crm_prospect = this_.id                and p.fk_e0_prof_nodo = this_.fk_e0_prof_nodo) as formula1664_0_, 
                    ( select i.num_dipendenti from e2_crm_info_camerali_prosp i              where i.fk_e2_crm_prospect = this_.id               
                        and i.dt_inserimento = ( select max(p.dt_inserimento)                     
                                                    from e2_crm_info_camerali_prosp p                        
                                                    where p.fk_e2_crm_prospect = this_.id )              ) as formula1665_0_ 

from e2_crm_prospects this_ where this_.fl_duplicato=? ) 

SELECT * FROM query WHERE __hibernate_row_nr__ BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

The problem is that the resulting data is not ordered by the `numero` column.

Using the old dialect the paginated query was translated with a `TOP` clause with an `ORDER BY numero` at the end of the query and the rows where ordered correctly.

The query is build using criteria and ordered and paginated like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ProspectRicerca.class,"padre"); 

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(Constant.PROSPECT_FLAG_DUPLICATO, false));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("numero"));

criteria.setFirstResult(pageNumber*numElementForPage);
criteria.setMaxResults(numElementForPage);

lista = criteria.list();
```

The hibernate version is 3.6.10 and we use Sql Server 2008

This is the result of the query executed in sql server, as you can see the rows are not ordered (the `__hibernate_row_nr__` column is coherent with the `numero` column order.

[image]

Comment: Because you didn't say that you wanted your results ordered by `numero`, just that you wanted them **numbered** according to that column.  They're too different things.  You still need an `ORDER BY`.  Also, don't use the inclusive bounds of `BETWEEN` - treat the numbers like an array range, and use `<`.

Comment: Tnx @Clockwork-Muse for your fast comment. 
The criteria query is built using criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("numero")) and with the old dialect the ORDER BY is added but not with the new dialect. Is it not enough? I edited the question inserting the addOrder clause.

Comment: ...I think we need to see the entire statement, but I can already tell you have a problem: your pagination is potentially off.  `ROW_NUMBER` starts with **1**, so your current code is going to have 1 fewer elements on the first page (either that, or you end up skipping the first page of results entirely....).  Otherwise, what happens if you repeat the criteria after the pagination?

Comment: Ok @Clockwork-Muse, I added the entire sql statement as translated. I didn't create the query so I don't have much control over the data

Comment: It looks like Hibernate [is having some problems with pagination on SQL Server](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11168?jql=text%20~%20%22criteria%20page%22), but the ticket only lists recent versions.  That's definitely not sufficient, though.

Comment: Ok it's something definitelycorrelated with the particular query..I executed the query without the formulas and it's ordered correctly